# sql amortization Schedule Multiple Loans

Tags: sql, amortization

I have the following code (which is not mine and found on a website which that person did a great job with this)This code does exactly what I need except I am still a newbie and don't understand how I can pass multiple loans through it. I have tried several ways to insert the set command for each declaration and each time I get errors. Any help would be appreciative.

```
\-------Section I think  my table values go in-------
```

I am updating this section in response to the answer given. So the Fiddle does what I need the way you have it setup but my only issue is I have read only access for reporting and running sql scripts for data. I can not create function to pass through. Sorry I should have mentioned that. My other issue it that all my loans will be based on 12 months period with varying total months. Sample table data below:

| LoanNumber | LoanStart | LoanEnd | LoanAmount | YrlyInt | LoanMonths |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11111 | 07/10/2023 | 07/06/2027 | 11341.98 | 6.65 | 48 |
| 22222 | 03/03/2022 | 02/25/2027 | 11242.78 | 3.25 | 60 |
| 33333 | 07/22/2020 | 07/25/2024 | 10496.91 | 3.43 | 48 |

I couldn't figure out the logic of how to make it a static period and then use my loanmonths for the actual calculations. SQL fiddle does it right but when I try to change it to my table data that is where it goes buggy.

How it should be:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q813c.png)

How mine is:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2eLCf.png)

[enter image description here][3]

[enter image description here][4]

[enter image description here][5]

Desired Output here.
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3j6D.png
[4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bg32u.png
[5]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQSHh.png

Comment: Please edit your question to cite your source for the original script. It helps everyone involved.

Comment: this is where I found it.       https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/loan-amortization-schedule-for-sql-server

Comment: I was able to read through the article. I believe this script is to be run by itself as s proof of concept that it is possible and it in fact works. It's probably not what you're looking for but I'd suggest using python to programmatically load and run the script with your different loans. I would even [check out this pyhton script](https://gist.github.com/tcramm0nd/f29bfd63a377249b79f0178919ea2b9f) over the SQL one you have above.

Comment: What is desired result?

Comment: I have attached Desired results in pictures for you to see. So basically when the script runs it will pass each loan through it creating a Amortization schedule for it so we can then tell how much in dollars per month we need to pay. So much easier then having to keep track in spreadsheet over the years. it get slows.  Thanks for all the help you are giving. I really appreciate it. I have trying to figure this out for six months.

Comment: Fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/0GByM0S- So I made a small adjustment which is make the yearly periods a static 12 and the script runs like it should other than it is using the months from the 1st row all loans when it is supposed to use each loan months for that particular loan. some maybe 36,48,60 etc......

Comment: I see what you are talking about and My parameters are coming from a table but I do not need the periods as they are not in the table but a static value of 12 which I figured out with your last script. My only issue now is that each loan has it own length of the loan in months so some loans maybe 36 months and some maybe 60 months.  Your last script change that to were it was using the 1st row data for the months on all the loans.....fiddle above shows that. It is exactly what I have been trying to do other than that one issue. https://dbfiddle.uk/tGo0qLuj

Comment: I don't need to filter the table but run it continuously through all the loans.  Again I just want to say thank you for all your help with this.

Answer (score 0):

See example.
Loans:

```
create table loans(id int,StartDate date,LoanAmount float,InterestRate float
     ,PeriodsPerYear int);
insert into loans values (1,'2023-01-01',10000.0,0.07,12);
insert into loans values (2,'2023-12-01',20000.0,0.05,12);
select * from loans;
```

Function

```
create or alter function calcLoan (
  @pN int =null
  ,@pIr float =null
  ,@pPv float =null
  ,@pNpy int =12
  ,@pBegDate date= null)
RETURNS @query TABLE (
    pmt_num int
  , payment_date date
  , beg_balance decimal(19,2)
  , scheduled_pmt decimal(19,2)
  , amt_to_intrest decimal(19,2)
  , amt_to_principal decimal(19,2)
  , end_balance decimal(19,2)
  )
Begin
DECLARE  @n int = 48,-- total # of payments 
@ir float = .0749,-- annual interest rate (note: enter as a decimal... So %5 would be entered as 0.05...) 
@pv float = 17864.78,-- present value (original loan amount) 
@npy int = 12,-- # of periods per year  
@beg_dt date = GETDATE(); -- the date of the first payment.  

if isnull(@pN,0)>0  set @n=@pN;
if isnull(@pIr,0.0)<>0.0  set @ir=@pIr;
if isnull(@pPv,0.0)<>0.0  set @pv=@pPv;
if isnull(@pNpy,0.0)<>0.0  set @npy=@pNpy;
if @pBegDate is null  set @beg_dt=@pBegDate;

WITH  cte_n1 (n) AS (
  SELECT 1 FROM (VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) n (n)
)
,cte_n2 (n) AS (
  SELECT 1 FROM cte_n1 a CROSS JOIN cte_n1 b
)
, cte_Tally (n) AS (
  SELECT TOP (@n) 
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY a.n) 
  FROM cte_n2 a CROSS JOIN cte_n2 b ORDER BY a.n 
) 
insert into @query
SELECT  pmt_num = t.n
  , pd.payment_date
  , beg_balance = CONVERT(decimal(19,2), pv.beg_balance)
  , scheduled_pmt = CONVERT(decimal(19, 2), pmt.pmt_calc)
  , amt_to_intrest = CONVERT(decimal(19,2), ipmt.ipmt)
  , amt_to_principal = CONVERT(decimal(19,2), ppmt.ppmt)
  , end_balance = CONVERT(decimal(19,2), pv.end_balance) 
FROM  cte_Tally t 
CROSS APPLY ( VALUES (
        @pv / (POWER(1 + (@ir / @npy), @n) - 1) 
            * ((@ir / @npy) * POWER(1 + (@ir / @npy), @n))
         )) pmt (pmt_calc) 
CROSS APPLY ( VALUES (
            ABS(-@pv * POWER(1 + (@ir / @npy), t.n-1) 
                + pmt.pmt_calc * (POWER(1 + (@ir / @npy), t.n-1) -1) / (@ir / @npy))
          , ABS(-@pv * POWER(1 + (@ir / @npy), t.n) 
                + pmt.pmt_calc * (POWER(1 + (@ir / @npy), t.n) -1) / (@ir / @npy)) 
         )) pv (beg_balance, end_balance) 
CROSS APPLY ( VALUES (pv.beg_balance * (@ir / @npy)
         ) ) ipmt (ipmt) 
CROSS APPLY ( VALUES (pmt.pmt_calc - ipmt.ipmt
             ) ) ppmt (ppmt) 
CROSS APPLY ( VALUES ( 
             CASE WHEN @npy <= 12 THEN DATEADD(MONTH, (12 / @npy) * (t.n - 1), @beg_dt) 
                  WHEN @npy = 26 THEN DATEADD(WEEK, 2 * (t.n - 1), @beg_dt) 
             ELSE DATEADD(DAY, (365 / @npy) * (t.n - 1), @beg_dt) 
             END 
       ) ) pd (payment_date)
;
return;
end;
```

Use of function

```
select * from loans l
cross apply calcLoan( 6,l.InterestRate,LoanAmount,l.PeriodsPerYear,l.StartDate)
```

Output

| id | StartDate | LoanAmount | Interest Rate | Periods PerYear | pmt_num | payment_date | beg_ balance | scheduled _pmt | amt_to_ intrest | amt_to_ principal | end_ balance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-01-01 | 10000 | 0.07 | 12 | 1 | 2024-03-06 | 10000.00 | 2536.56 | 58.33 | 2478.23 | 7521.77 |
| 1 | 2023-01-01 | 10000 | 0.07 | 12 | 2 | 2024-04-06 | 7521.77 | 2536.56 | 43.88 | 2492.69 | 5029.08 |
| 1 | 2023-01-01 | 10000 | 0.07 | 12 | 3 | 2024-05-06 | 5029.08 | 2536.56 | 29.34 | 2507.23 | 2521.85 |
| 1 | 2023-01-01 | 10000 | 0.07 | 12 | 4 | 2024-06-06 | 2521.85 | 2536.56 | 14.71 | 2521.85 | 0.00 |
| 2 | 2023-12-01 | 20000 | 0.05 | 12 | 1 | 2024-03-06 | 20000.00 | 5052.19 | 83.33 | 4968.86 | 15031.14 |
| 2 | 2023-12-01 | 20000 | 0.05 | 12 | 2 | 2024-04-06 | 15031.14 | 5052.19 | 62.63 | 4989.56 | 10041.58 |
| 2 | 2023-12-01 | 20000 | 0.05 | 12 | 3 | 2024-05-06 | 10041.58 | 5052.19 | 41.84 | 5010.35 | 5031.23 |
| 2 | 2023-12-01 | 20000 | 0.05 | 12 | 4 | 2024-06-06 | 5031.23 | 5052.19 | 20.96 | 5031.23 | 0.00 |

[Example fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/03rJuEZR)

See another example, where stored procedure converted to query
[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/QfLiQKYQ)

There we can put parameters for query from table as

```
WITH  params as (
  select LoanMonth pN,YrlyInt as pIr, LoanAmount pPv
        , PeriodsPerYear pNpy,LoanStart pBeg_dt
        ,LoanNumber
  from loans 
  -- filter loans 
  -- where LoanNumber=4  or LoanNumber in(5555,1111)
  )
```

Or parameters can be external

```
WITH  params as (
  select @LoanMonth pN,@YrlyInt as pIr, @LoanAmount pPv
        , @PeriodsPerYear pNpy,@LoanStart pBeg_dt
        ,@LoanNumber as LoanNumber
  )
```

```
WITH  params as (
  select LoanMonth pN,YrlyInt as pIr, LoanAmount pPv
        , PeriodsPerYear pNpy,LoanStart pBeg_dt
        ,LoanNumber
  from loans -- where LoanNumber=4
  )
, cte_Tally (n) AS (
  select rn
  from(
  SELECT pN, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY a.n) rn
  FROM (VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) a (n)
  CROSS JOIN (VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) b (n)
  CROSS JOIN (VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) c (n)
  CROSS JOIN (VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) d (n)
  cross apply (select pN from params)e
  ) x
  where rn<=pN
) 

SELECT  LoanNumber
  , pmt_num = t.n
  , pd.payment_date
  , beg_balance = CONVERT(decimal(19,2), pv.beg_balance)
  , scheduled_pmt = CONVERT(decimal(19, 2), pmt.pmt_calc)
  , amt_to_intrest = CONVERT(decimal(19,2), ipmt.ipmt)
  , amt_to_principal = CONVERT(decimal(19,2), ppmt.ppmt)
  , end_balance = CONVERT(decimal(19,2), pv.end_balance) 
FROM  cte_Tally t cross apply params
CROSS APPLY ( VALUES (
        pPv / (POWER(1 + (pIr / pNpy), pN) - 1) 
            * ((pIr / pNpy) * POWER(1 + (pIr / pNpy), pN))
         )) pmt (pmt_calc) 
CROSS APPLY ( VALUES (
            ABS(-pPv * POWER(1 + (pIr / pNpy), t.n-1) 
                + pmt.pmt_calc * (POWER(1 + (pIr / pNpy), t.n-1) -1) / (pIr / pNpy))
          , ABS(-pPv * POWER(1 + (pIr / pNpy), t.n) 
                + pmt.pmt_calc * (POWER(1 + (pIr / pNpy), t.n) -1) / (pIr / pNpy)) 
         )) pv (beg_balance, end_balance) 
CROSS APPLY ( VALUES (pv.beg_balance * (pIr / pNpy)
         ) ) ipmt (ipmt) 
CROSS APPLY ( VALUES (pmt.pmt_calc - ipmt.ipmt
             ) ) ppmt (ppmt) 
CROSS APPLY ( VALUES ( 
             CASE WHEN pNpy <= 12 THEN DATEADD(MONTH, (12 / pNpy) * (t.n - 1), pBeg_dt) 
                  WHEN pNpy = 26 THEN DATEADD(WEEK, 2 * (t.n - 1), pBeg_dt) 
             ELSE DATEADD(DAY, (365 / pNpy) * (t.n - 1), pBeg_dt) 
             END 
       ) ) pd (payment_date)
order by LoanNumber,pmt_num
;
```